# how to convert SQLite database to Realm database in swift

Tags: swift, sqlite, realm

I have sqlite file, but I am trying to implement Realm in my application.Is there any way to convert SQLite database into Realm? or how can i use my sqlite file into Realm.Is there any useful tutorial or suggestions?Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Switching from SQLite to Realm should be pretty straightforward. Realm supports all of the same major data types as SQLite, so for most flat tables, it should just be a matter of making a matching model object schema in Realm and simply copying the values across. Realm supports NULL values for every data type it supports, so you should be able to create similar NULL checking queries to what you have now (Although without knowing what sort of NULL checking you are doing, I can't say for sure if it will actually simplify your queries).

The major caveat in moving from SQLite to Realm is how relations are represented. Realm doesn't really have a traditional implementation of primary and foreign keys, so you may need to change the way how your objects reference each other. Data in Realm is exposed as objects, and so relations are managed as object properties in the schema itself. For a one-to-one relationship, you can simply include the object type as a property, and for one-to-many relationships, you can include an array of linking objects. For many-to-many relationships, Realm also provides a 'back linking' API that lets an object work out which other objects in which it belongs.

Beyond this, there's not really a recommended way for moving to Realm from SQLite, since it will most likely depend on the way your data has been structured. There's not really any official migration guides or tools at the moment (For that reason mentioned above), but it's something we're looking into.

In summary, how to import SQLite to Realm is:

1. Create Realm model classes mapped from SQLite tables.
2. Read the data from SQLite, then copy the data to Realm.

I hope that answered your questions.